# Is it possible to hit a full-text index without using a function specifically designed for them?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

There are several functions that are specifically designed to hit full-text indexes. I think that the following is a complete list:

- `CONTAINS`
- `CONTAINSTABLE`
- `FREETEXT`
- `FREETEXTTABLE`

Is it possible to hit a full-text index without using one of these functions? Whether or not you have hit the index can be proven by pasting in your execution plan.

Comment: no how should the program(any sql server ) know what you want

Comment: @nbk I'd presume that there are some `LIKE` searches that are logically equivalent to a full-text search.

Comment: no, like would hit the fullt text index only a "normal" one, LIKE could also make a full Database scan

Comment: @nbk For what it's worth, I find "SQL Server doesn't do this because it doesn't make any sense at all to do that" to be a good answer. Proving a negative is hard, but that's a pretty good shot at it.

Comment: you always can make an EXPLAIN and view what sql server does or will do

Comment: @nbk On a case-by-case basis, yes. But what I'm after is the general answer.

Comment: the first comment ist your answer, you can nit access the full text index without special functions, they are at a separate part of the source code, that is for every rdms

Comment: @nbk Sounds good to me. Feel free to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to hit a full-text index without using one of these functions?

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16#queries) does a pretty good job of [pointing this out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16).

> Write full-text queries by using the predicates CONTAINS and FREETEXT and the rowset-valued functions CONTAINSTABLE and FREETEXTTABLE with a SELECT statement.

> Full-text queries use a small set of Transact-SQL predicates (CONTAINS and FREETEXT) and functions (CONTAINSTABLE and FREETEXTTABLE).

The architecture overview calls out how [these functions are integrated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16#querying) into general query processing (essentially explaining why they are needed while not explicitly doing so).

> I'd presume that there are some LIKE searches that are logically equivalent to a full-text search.

Like isn't a semantic search. Could full-text have new functionality added to it to enhance this? Sure, but it doesn't right now and it would change the way `like` behaves which is a pattern rather than semantic search.